# Single tab in TabLayout is not covering the entire width

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I have created a view pager with TabLayout. Now the issue is if I have 2 or more tabs then everything is fine. But if I am having only one tab then it is not covering the entire screen width. PFA the xml layout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        style="@style/TabLayout"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/ssrToolbar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llButtonLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Also here are the two images

[image: single tab]

[image: two tabs]

Comment: Hey guys any answers for this question?? I am unable to find a soln yet

Comment: hi... i need answer to this question

Comment: me too. Any solution ?

Answer (score 26):

If someones still interested you should add this property for TabLayout in xml   `app:tabMaxWidth="big_number"`, for big_number i chose 2000dp. If you are not assigning any value default implementation subtracts widths measured specifications size with `TAB_MIN_WIDTH_MARGIN` value.

Comment: Can I do it programitically ?